# Jhipster apache tomcat install

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat, jhipster

I'm using JHipster to build a web application (awesome project, keep going guys :).
I'm using a server where apache is already installed deploying a php app (http://www.myurl.com)

I'm trying to deploy my JHipster app under another url (http://www.myurl.com/my_project)

I tried :

1. rewrite rule to redirect /my_project http://localhost:PORT/my_project using my own tomcat install
2. using runnable jhipster war
3. changing some cong in yml file to add context under server > context-path

Nothing is working fine :

1. access to first page webapp ok but 404 to any other pages
2. blank page, unable to load resources because context is missing I think
3. doesn't change anything

Any other idea? Something I forget? Something related to webpack ?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Which version of JHipster and are you using React or Angular?

Comment: Angular and JHipster 4.14.1

Answer (score 0):

Use apache(httpd) proxying to redirect calls to your jHipster application to your tomcat
the configuration is meant to be put in apache configuration files you must have proxying mod enabled in apache but if my memories are good proxying user sessions from apache httpd to tomcat can be quite tricky. The following syntax is what you are looking for 
ProxyPass "/images"  "http://www.example.com/"
ProxyPassReverse "/images"  "http://www.example.com/"

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Comment: this is what I did when I said : "rewrite rule to redirect /my_project http://localhost:PORT/my_project using my own tomcat install"